# Find the smallest possible value of $a^4+b^4+c^4-136abc$

Tags: optimization

> Let $a$, $b$, and $c$ be real numbers such that $a+b+c=-68$ and $ab+bc+ca=1156$. The smallest possible value of $a^4+b^4+c^4-136abc$ is $k$. Find the remainder when $k$ is divided by $1000$.

I would solve this question by first noting that $(a+b+c)^2 = a^2+b^2+c^2 +2*1156 = 68^2 \implies a^2+b^2+c^2 = 68^2-2*1156$. Then I am wondering what I should do next. I could square $a^2+b^2+c^2$ to get $a^4+b^4+c^4 +2(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+a^2c^2) = 2312^2$. I am not sure what to do next.

Comment: Real numbers ? You probably mean integers.

Comment: @Peter No, I think real numbers is right (at least that's how the question was written).

Comment: But what should the remainder of $k$ divided by $1000$ mean if $k$ is not an integer ?

Comment: @Peter It should be an integer otherwise you are right.

Comment: Perhaps, the given conditions imply that $k$ must be an integer ...

Comment: Have you tried calculus?

Comment: Note that $a^2+b^2+c^2=2ab+2bc+2ca$.